# Multiple Canvas Elements on a HTML 5 page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas

Can I have multiple Canvases on an HTML 5 Page with an image on each of the Canvas. I basically need to make use of the [JS manipulation Plugin](http://joelb.me/jsmanipulate/) on all the images for my app and this plugin requires the image to be on the canvas.

Will having multiple canvas and an image inside them, affect or slow the performance of the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple canvas-elements. The performance of your page will not suffer from the fact that there are multiple canvases. What will affect your performance is the redrawing of the canvases. As for the images what will determine the performance is how much redrawing that has to be done.

You can read more at: [HTML5 multiple canvas on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020910/html5-multiple-canvas-on-a-single-page)

Answer (score 2):

Canvas element is extremely fast at redrawing. It's far more fast than SVG which makes it very efficient as a drawing tool for web development.

You can use as many canvases as you want and they shouldn't have a negative impact on your page performance.

Also, canvas elements are loaded within the whole page, but the code that loads images and draws into the canvas *usually* is executed *after* the page is fully loaded, so the only thing that can slow your page's performance is what you do inside your different canvas elements, not the number of those elements you use in your page. Also, if you start drawing after the page is loaded, no matter what you do on your canvas elements, as the page will be fully loaded when you start drawing.

Keep in mind that javascript is used for drawing onto canvas. If you use heavy processes to make your drawings you could find that one canvas drawing blocks the other one until it's finished. Try to construct your drawing code in the less blocking way you can to avoid that.